# Generating curved polygons

Tags: python, math, polygon, spline

How do i add curvature to the vertices and edges of polygons.

I'm trying to create some curved polygons such as these [curved vertices](http://data:image/png;base64,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), [curved edge shapes](https://p7.hiclipart.com/preview/443/894/548/reuleaux-triangle-curve-of-constant-width-circle-polygonal-thumbnail.jpg) or  [even both](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsS1M.png)

How would you go generating these shapes.
I've looked into Bezier curves but they seem quite involving, I want to know if there are any simpler solution before I commit to this method.

Here's my code for generating polygons if anyone needs a starting point.

```
def gen_poly(sides, radius=1, rotation=0):
    seg = math.pi * 2 / sides
    x_list = []
    y_list = []
    for i in range(sides): 
        x = math.sin(seg * i + rotation) * radius
        y = math.cos(seg * i + rotation) * radius
        x_list.append(x)
        y_list.append(y)
    x_list.append(x_list[0])
    y_list.append(y_list[0]) 
    return x_list,y_list
x,y=polygon(5) 

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y, marker='.')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
```

Comment: A [polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon) "...is a plane figure that is described by a finite number of **straight line segments** connected to form a closed polygonal chain".

Comment: You don't have to manually code bézier curves (although there are plenty options for that), [matplotlib got them covered](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/shapes_and_collections/quad_bezier.html).

Comment: You could take a look at [Chaikin's Corner Cutting Algorithm](https://observablehq.com/@pamacha/chaikins-algorithm). Here's a discussion on [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068504/where-to-find-python-implementation-of-chaikins-corner-cutting-algorithm) implementations.

Comment: @SirRaffleBuffle Exactly what I'm after, thanks! If you know of any other algorithms for generating any type of continues polygons such as [reuleaux shapes](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReuleauxPolygon.html) or [CST (page 15-16](http://www.brendakulfan.com/docs/CST3.pdf), please let me know. I'm trying to build a large set of varied polygons.