# Python - generate spline from XY point list pymunk

Tags: python, physics

I have a XY points list (trackP[][]) for car track, and i want to "smooth" it.
Because in pymunk (and other physics engines) there is no more complex shapes than polys (or segments), in my opinion I need to interpolate data points, to remove sharp corners... How can I do that? I will need that knowledge to generate "Hill climb racing" track too (smooth track from set of points).
My track at the moment (it is procedural generated from seed):[track](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Orufk.png)

EDIT:
I've found an answer, it's chaikin's corner cutting algorithm. Below is my "fork" of code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068504/)

```
def chaikins_corner_cutting(coords, refinements=5):
coords.insert(0,coords[len(coords)-1])
coords.append(coords[1])
coords = np.array(coords)

for _ in range(refinements):
    L = coords.repeat(2, axis=0)
    R = np.empty_like(L)
    R[0] = L[0]
    R[2::2] = L[1:-1:2]
    R[1:-1:2] = L[2::2]
    R[-1] = L[-1]
    coords = L * 0.75 + R * 0.25
coords2 = coords.tolist()

for i in range(2**refinements): 
    coords2.pop(0)
    i+=1
for i in range(2**refinements): 
    coords2.pop(len(coords2)-1)
return coords2
```

And here is final effect after some angle fixing: [image: Track]

Answer (score 1):

I am sure a lot of implementations exist for Splines in Python. The one I know best is availably in SciPy:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.spline.html

```
>>> import scipy.interpolate as spi
>>> x = [0,1,2,3]
>>> y = [1,5,3,4]
>>> fsmooth = spi.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x, y)
>>> fsmooth([0.5, 0.9, 1.1, 1.5])
array([4.3125, 5.0185, 4.9215, 4.1875])
```

However, this works for functions `y=f(x)` in a mathematical sense where for each x value only one y value is visited. Your track is not a function in this sense. So you would need to find a different representation first.

Comment: Yeah, i have thought same too, but I've only found data splines, so... But thanks for help

Comment: On the second thought, it may be useful for "hill climb racing" style track, so one "category" of problems is solved